# Проблемы и недопонимания в Subsurf моделировании и топологии

Tags: 3d, blender

уважаемые знатоки. Подскажите пожалуйста как бороться с косяками Subsurf'a в blender. Имеется простенькая модель, но по своей неграмотности в 3D не могу решить проблему с топологией. После добавления Subsurf модификатора , на модели выступают странные вздутия, даже грани поддержки не помогают их избежать[image: Странные "вздутия?" на модели после Subserf'а]
[image: Топология модели]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Такие проблемы решаются с помошью гайдовой модели и модификатора shrinkwrap. Подробно техника описана тут:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rlMzsBWtPY&ab_channel=CGMasters